Kivy black screen with no errors
So I'm trying to make an android .apk file using kivy, but It's just giving me a black screen. It works up until I declare the root in my randomnumber.kv file. Here is my python code:
import kivy

kivy.require("1.9.0")

import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class RandomNumber(App):
  def build(self):
    return BoxLayout()

class MyRoot(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__()

def generate_number(self):
    self.random_label.text = str(random.randint(0, 2000))

randomApp = RandomNumber()
randomApp.run()

My randomnumber.kv looks like:
<MyRoot>:
    random_label: random_label
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Random Number"
            font_size: 30
            color: 0, 0.62, 0.96

        Label:
            id: random_label
            text: "_"
            font_size: 30

        Button:
            text: "Generate"
            font_size: 15
            on_press: root.generate_number()

`
I'm using a tutorial and even the code from the tutorial doesn't work. Help!!!
I tried editing the file name and how the kivy file was being called, but it still gave me a black screen. Also tried print statements in various places, but nothing

Your build() method is still returning an empty BoxLayout, which is just a black screen. You need to change:
return BoxLayout()

to:
return MyRoot()

Note the syntax of the kv language says regarding a rule using <>:

With the braces it's a rule. Without them, it's a root widget.

See the documentation.
Or you can just remove the <> in your kv file and eliminate your build() method completely.
